# Steps to solve integral in analytic continuation problem

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I was reading
[this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_continuation) Wikipedia article’s example of analytic continuation using the function: $$f(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k(z-1)^k$$
I was able to understand the process until this step:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\sum_{m=0}^{n}{n \choose m}(a-1)^{n-m}(re^{i\theta})^m}{(re^{i\theta})^k}d\theta=(-1)^ka^{-k-1}$$

Can someone explain how these two expressions are equivalent? Note that k will always be an integer. I believe this is all the needed information to explain this equivalence but if it is not the rest should be in the above Wikipedia article. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Let $p \ne 0$. Note that

$$
\int_0^{2\pi} (e^{i\theta})^p d\theta=  \int_0^{2\pi} e^{pi\theta}d\theta =  \frac{e^{pi\theta}}{pi}|_{\theta = 0}^{2\pi} = 0.
$$

So in the integral you're having trouble with, the only summand the value of which is non-zero is precisely when the numerator $(re^{i\theta})^n$ cancels out with the denominator $(re^{i\theta})^k$. You should be able to work out the rest.

Comment: I was able to get to this with your method: $\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}(-1)^n{n \choose k}(a-1)^{n-k}$ but I cannot figure out what to do next. How would you show that this power series equals $(-1)^ka^{-k-1}$

Comment: There is an answer to the question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4577981/about-a-sum-with-a-combinatorial-coefficient).