# About a sum with a combinatorial coefficient

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, summation, binomial-theorem

I'm reading the [Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_continuation) on analytic continuation and I got stuck in the last step of the worked example. How to get the following result? $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n{n\choose k}(a-1)^{n-k}=(-1)^ka^{-k-1}$$

Obviously the sum starts from $n=k$ because ${n\choose k}=0$ for all $k>n$. I have tried by calculating some first terms of the sum and using the identity $${n\choose k}={n-1\choose k-1}+{n-1\choose k}$$ to see if there would be a useful pattern but I have had no success. Could someone tell how to arrive to the rhs from the lhs? This [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3395306/steps-to-solve-integral-in-analytic-continuation-problem) is about the same exmple and there is no answer to the op's comment. So here is the comment as a proper question.

EDIT: I had a typo on the lhs: it's actually $(-1)^n$ instead of $(-1)^k$.

Thanks to Mike Earnest's answer suggesting Newton's Binomial Theorem I calculated $$(x+1)^{-n}=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}{-n\choose i}x^i.$$ By simplifying the binomial coefficients $$\frac{-n(-n-1)(-n-2)...(-n-i+1)}{i!}=(-1)^i\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)...(n+i-1)}{i!}=(-1)^i\frac{n+i-1}{i!(n-1)}=(-1)^i{n-1 +i\choose i}=(-1)^i{n-1+i\choose n-1}$$
and then choosing $x=(a-1)$ gives: $$\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}(-1)^n{n\choose k}(a-1)^{n-k}=a^{-k-1}.$$ So I'm only missing the $(-1)^k$. Where can that be found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}}&\color{blue}{(-1)^n{n\choose k}(a-1)^{n-k}}\\
> &=\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}(-1)^n\binom{n}{k}(a-1)^{n-k}\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+k}\binom{n+k}{k}(a-1)^{n}\tag{2}\\
> &=(-1)^k\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{-k-1}{n}(a-1)^{n}\tag{3}\\
> &=(-1)^k(1+(a-1))^{-k-1}\tag{4}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=(-1)^ka^{-k-1}}
> \end{align*}
> and the claim follows.

**Comment:**

- In (1) we start with index $n=k$ since $\binom{n}{k}=0$ if $n<k$.
- In (2) we shift the index to start with $n=0$ again.
- In (3) we use the binomial identities $\binom{p}{q}=\binom{p}{p-q}$ and $\binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{q}(-1)^q$. We get
  \begin{align*}
  \binom{n+k}{k}=\binom{n+k}{n}=\binom{-(n+k)+n-1}{n}(-1)^n=\binom{-k-1}{n}(-1)^n
  \end{align*}
- In (4) we use the *[binomial series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)*.

Comment: @MikeEarnest: Oh, yes. Many thanks for the hint. :-)

Comment: Thank you for a very clear answer!

Comment: @Jonne: You're welcome. I've added some details.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use this general fact:
$$
\sum_{n= 0}^\infty \binom nkx^n = \frac{x^k}{(1-x)^{k+1}}\qquad (|x|<1)
$$
In your case, you want $x=a-1$.

To prove this, let $S_k=\sum_{n\ge 0}\binom nkx^k$. Using Pascal's identity, $\binom nk=\binom{n-1}{k-1}+\binom {n-1}k$, you can split this into two sums, and derive the equation
$$
S_k = xS_{k-1}+xS_k,
$$
which, combined with the base case $S_0=(1-x)^{-1}$,  quickly leads to a proof by induction that $S_k=x^k(1-x)^{-(k+1)}$.

This also follows from  Newton's binomial theorem:
$$
\sum_{n\ge 0}\binom n{n-k}x^n
=\sum_{n\ge 0}(-1)^{n-k}\binom{-(k+1)}{n-k}x^n
=x^k\sum_{n\ge 0}\binom{-(k+1)}{n-k}(-x)^{n-k}=x^k(1-x)^{-(k+1)}
$$

Comment: It looks to me that the "general fact" is a strange one. $0=rhs$ for all $n<k$ and for $n=k$ it says $x^k=rhs$. Doesn't look correct to me. (If it is true, then it leaves an unwanted minus sign on the rhs. $1-x=-a$ for $x=a-1$.)

Comment: Wikipedia agrees it is correct, see second equation in "Ordinary generating functions" section: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Ordinary_generating_functions Your complaint makes no sense; there is no "when $n=k$", it is a summation over all $n$.

Comment: True, it's a sum over all of them. I'll see the links, thank you. Only the minus sign remains a problem. Or is it also something my tired brain misreads/misunderstands?

Comment: Several proofs here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1941603/177399

Comment: @Jonne You copied down the formula from the analytic continuation article wrong. It is supposed to be $(-1)^n$ in your summation, not $(-1)^k$. This is why you were unable to complete the proof.

Comment: I edited the question, it is correct now. Thanks again. I need to go to bed now, I will return to this tomorrow.